# How to add default images into theme customizer image control?

Tags: php, functions, customization, ajax, theme-customizer

I am trying to figure out how I can pre-load a theme customizer image control with images I have selected. Is their a way to point the control to a directory so they automatically show up in the uploaded list? So the user can select an image from the list if they like it.

If anyone could explain this I would greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT: I have decided to add more information along with the bounty.**

When a user is using the theme customizer(built with the theme customizer API), and they end up deciding they don't like the current background image and wan't to edit it, so they choose the background image setting/control to change it. Well I would like for a group of images to appear in the dropdown by default so if the user wants one then they can choose it, or else upload a new image. So when they select the drop down it will have say 5 or so images pre-loaded inside.

I think that this probably needs to be done by pointing the control to a folder but I am not sure how. I have seen this before but I cant remember where.

I am using the default image control in the theme customizer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Our journey starts [`here`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php#L436) with the `WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control` class, which is a [`WP_Customize_Image_Control`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php#L310).

I'd imagine offering these built-in backgrounds in a new tab alongside the existing `Upload New` and `Uploaded` tabs. There are at least two ways of achieving the following: either creating your own modified class based off of the `WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control` class, or altering its default behavior by hijacking the global `$wp_customize` instead. The former is the longer way (albeit perhaps cleaner), wherein we would first of all we have to define our new control:

```
class WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control_Defaults extends WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control {
    public function __construct( $manager ) {
    ...
        $this->add_tab( 'builtins', __('Built-ins'), array( $this, 'tab_builtins' ) );

    ...
    public function tab_builtins() {
    ...
}
```

Then remove the default background image control that was [registered by default](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L791) and add our own new class:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function( $wp_customize ) {
    /* Substitute the default control for our new one */
    $wp_customize->remove_control( 'background_image' );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control_Defaults( $wp_customize ) );
}, 11, 1 );
```

The new tab would then simply echo out a set of predefined images that are shipped with your theme, akin to how the default [`tab_uploaded`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php#L449) functions with minor adjustments. This function would be the same for either when you're using a custom class, or trying out the faster approach.

The faster, more compact approach involves making the default control dance to our tune after initialization like so:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function( $wp_customize ) {

    $control = $wp_customize->get_control( 'background_image' );
    $control->add_tab( 'builtins', __('Built-ins'), function() {
        /* Supply a list of built-in background that come with your theme */
        $backgrounds = array(
            'images/bg-01.png', 'images/bg-02.png', ...
        );

        global $wp_customize;
        $control = $wp_customize->get_control( 'background_image' );

        foreach ( (array) $backgrounds as $background )
            $control->print_tab_image( esc_url_raw( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/' . $background ) );

    } );

}, 11, 1 );
```

Again, if you choose to use your own class, you'd do pretty much the same, `add_tab` which does a `print_tab_image` on all your preset backgrounds. Pretty straightforward. I'm sure you can further improve the code with various odds and ends, but overall this looks like the way to go I think.

Questions, ideas, thoughts welcome.

[image: Default background images in Theme Customizer]